# C++ Socket application closes for no reason

Tags: c++, sockets

Basically I am creating a socket server in C++ which accepts connections, and then creates threads to send data to those connections.
For this I've used a while loop which basically is:

```
while (TRUE){
    listen_sock = listen(sock, SOMAXCONN);
    if (listen_sock == 0){
        accept_sock = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
        if(accept_sock == INVALID_SOCKET){ 
            cout << "part 5\n";
            printf("accepting connection failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        thread thrd(send_dat, accept_sock);
        thrd.detach();
    }
    else if (listen_sock == SOCKET_ERROR){
        cout << "part 4\n";
        printf("\n\nlistening on socket failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
}
```

Basically send_dat(SOCKET accept_sock) is a function that just sends data to accept_sock socket:

```
void send_dat(SOCKET accept_sock){
/*variable declarations here*/
data = recv(accept_sock, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
if (data == SOCKET_ERROR){
    cout << "part -1\n";
    throw runtime_error("Failed to receive data");
    WSAGetLastError();
}
data_res = response(data);
send_sock = send(accept_sock, data_res_len, data_res, 0);
if (send_sock == SOCKET_ERROR){
    cout << "part -2\n";
    throw runtime_error("Failed to send data");
    WSAGetLastError();
}
}
```

The problem is that whenever I run it, it just closes after sending data to one user once, without any error or messages.
Why is this happening? Please help.

Comment: `while(TRUE)` doesn't compile (you meant `while(true)` maybe). Also, I don't understand the point of mixing `std::cout` and `printf()`. There may be other mistakes but anyway, you should do the debug part yourself before posting on StackOverflow, and if you did, please include the debug details in your question, and provide a minimal and reproducible example of your issue.

Comment: Apart from weird style, I guess that this might be one of your problems: `thrd.detach();`. What you are trying to do with this infinite loop?

Comment: You should only open your listener socket once, then you can call accept from within the loop

Comment: @Fareanor Microsoft define `TRUE` to be 1

Comment: @AlanBirtles Oh I didn't know that, I'm not used to Microsoft headers. Thanks for the rectification.

Comment: This is happening because of The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: "Your Computer Always Does Exactly What You Tell It To Do, Instead Of What You Want It To Do". You told your computer: start a thread that receives and sends one message, then terminates without even closing the client socket. So that's what your computer does, handling one message, and leaking a file descriptor.

Comment: @ShotoTodoroki "*whenever I run it, it just closes after sending data to one user once*" - what does that mean, exactly? What closes? The connection? The application? Please be more specific. Like Sam said, your thread is missing logic to handle multiple messages per connection, and also to close the accepted socket when done using it. Also, `listen()` should be called *before* entering the loop. And you are creating your `thread` even if `accept()` fails.